# asp.net CompleteRequest does not prevent processing of other postback events

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Page_Load I have the following...

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
  ...
}
else
{
   if (someCondition)
   {
      HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
      return;
   }
   ... Normal Processing ...
}
```

Two things I don't understand

1. I set a breakpoint at the call to `CompleteRequest` to verify that I get there, and I do. Hitting <kbd>F10</kbd> to step moves to the `return` statement without hitting the breakpoint I set at `Application_EndRequest` in `global.asax`
2. The postback was the result of hitting a button on the web page. After hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> to continue from the `return` statement, the breakpoint I set on the button Click handler is hit. When I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> here, execution does stop at the breakpoint at `Application_EndRequest`.

I thought that `CompleteRequest` was supposed to go directly to `EndRequest` and prevent the processing of any further page events.

Comment: And are you using Integrated Pipeline ?

Comment: That's an interesting question - thank you.

Comment: Sorry - still typing ... I'm using a Win7 development machine and testing within VS2010. I believe that it is using IIS7 with integrated pipeline. The DefaultAppPool is integrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it isn't - dev server integrated in Visual Studio isn't running in integrated mode. Test:

```
var type = typeof(HttpRuntime);
var method = type.GetProperty("UseIntegratedPipeline", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
bool useIntegratedPipeline = (bool)method.GetValue(null, null);
// false for integrated dev server
```

As for the CompleteRequest, from the reflector, the method looks like this:

```
internal void CompleteRequest() {
  this._requestCompleted = true;
  if (HttpRuntime.UseIntegratedPipeline) {
    HttpContext context = this._application.Context;
    if (context != null && context.NotificationContext != null) {
      context.NotificationContext.RequestCompleted = true;
    }
  }
}
```

So unless you're running web application on IIS in integrated mode, nothing will happen immediately after CompleteRequest() call. The edification here is, dev server doesn't have the same behavior as IIS.